# Run RegisterStartupScript multiple times in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, code-behind, registerstartupscript

Good day Everyone,

The following is part of my code

start code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script>loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info1)</script>",false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp2", "<script>loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2)</script>",false);
}
```

end of code

The `loadAdditionalInfoDialog()` function will prompt a small window and let user to key in some info and then click on "OK" button to proceed to next step.

But, when I click on Button1, I can only see the secoond `RegisterStartupScript`, which is `loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2)` works, it will prompt the small window, and I can key in some info and click on "OK" button to proceed to next step.

Because of this, I CAN NOT enter info for the first `RegisterStartupScript`, which is `loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info1)`.

Would like to ask for solution which is, when I click on Button1, I can first enter info for `loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info1)` and then click on "OK" button, then continue enter info for `loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2)`.

Thousand of thanks.

Actually the Button1_Click is just a button I create to do testing.
In fact, I only will call the loadAdditionalInfoDialog() when I get data in a Repeater :

```
protected void btnRedeemAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach( RepeaterItem itm in repGiftResults.Items )
        {
            /*
            code to get all those parameter
            */
            if (pr.AdditionalFieldsEnabled == true)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script>loadAdditionalInfoDialog(1," + pr.ID + "," + giftId + ",'" + txtQty.ClientID + "'," + tokenId + ")</script>", false);
                        
                    }
        }
    }
```

Thus, I think it is hard for me to call the second time loadAdditonalInfoDialog() when I click on "OK" button, because I need to get many parameter in the repeater.

Comment: Do this have any answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your code should work fine, Just make sure that your info1 and info2 are defined and revise your logic in loadAdditionalInfoDialog. just for test put an alert in it. 
and also you could make both calls in one block.

**Update:** Here is what i understand you want to do from your comments:

In you repeater template add a hidden field

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf" runat="server" />
```

In your code behind you could try something like this

```
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in cdcatalog.Items)
        {
            // Put your condition here like  if (pr.AdditionalFieldsEnabled == true) in my case to make it simple I'm just using the index
            if (item.ItemIndex == 1)
            {
                //Get the hidden fiels to save your parameters for the next call you can add multiple parameters 1;2;3;4 and read it using js
                HiddenField hdf = item.FindControl("hdf") as HiddenField;
                hdf.Value = "info2";
                // Pass the client ID for the hidden field so you can access it in loadAdditionalInfoDialog to retrieve parameter
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), String.Format("temp_{0}",item.ItemIndex),
                                                   String.Format("<script>loadAdditionalInfoDialog('info1',{0});</script>",hdf.ClientID),
                                                    false);
            }
        }
```

and in your script you can do something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadAdditionalInfoDialog(param, hdfId) {
            // Do whatever yout want here
            var info = prompt("Please enter ", param);

            if (info != null) {
                // Do whatever you want with the info you collected 

                // This code should be in your ok click button to check whether you should call the second window.
                if (info !== undefined) {
                    loadAdditionalInfoDialog(hdfId.value);
                }
            }


        }

    </script>
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: Salam Sejahtera. Actually, when I run my code in debug mode, when run the first RegisterStartupScript, which is loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info1), the window still prompt out.

But when I continue press "F5" in my compiler (MS Visual Studio 2010), It continue run to next code, which is second RegisterStartupScript, and the first pop out window (which is refer to first RegisterStartupScript) will disappear, and substitute by second pop out window. 

What I want is, I want to fill in the info in first pop out window and click on "OK" button before the second pop out window come out.

Comment: that happens because your code is not stopping when you show your window, it just moves on the second call and re display the new window. one thing you could do is that you call the second method loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2) after the user fills in the first one. You mentioned that you have an "OK" button you could call it from this click handler. you will need to add one more param to the method to detect whether this is the first or second call

loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2,isFirstInfo)

Comment: I understand what your idea.

Actually my question is not simple as what I post, I already edit my post and add more details. Can you help me have a look again.

Thank you.

Or Can I chat with you in gtalk or email or facebook?

Comment: You could save your values into a HiddenField
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

and in your Ok Button click handler just read these values again and call loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2). if this didn't work let me know.

Comment: Actually, the first part of code that I post is just a testing code. In fact, I have a repeater, and the loadAdditionalInfoDialog() maybe call more than 2 times (depends on item in Repeater). Thus, it is quite hard for me to do it at OK button, since it may more than 2 times to call the function. I already added in additional code at the bottom part of my question. Would like to ask you have any idea or not. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still looking for way to do this.
This is what worked for me, implemented in your example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", "    <script>loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info1); loadAdditionalInfoDialog(info2); </script>",false);

}
```

I merged the two process into one, if you need to do one first and then the second it may help